# Optimization of mov instruction based on ARM architecture

Tags: optimization, arm, compiler-optimization, instruction-set, mov

I'm graduate student in Korea and interested in the optimization eliminating `mov` instruction during compile time.

Especially, in ARM ISA, I have observed that the mov instruction is used to handle stack operation (`push` or `pop`) and PC address handling for procedure call.

During compile time, `mov` instructions can be eliminated by using high optimization level, but the `mov` instruction in ARM architecture is used to handle procedure call. Thus, I think that they cannot be eliminated unlike general mov instruction for inter-register data copy.

Can these `mov` instructions for procedure call be eliminated during compile time? It there anybody who knows these concepts or sources?

I can't find such information...

---

**Modified at 2017. 10. 24.**

When I build the source code with gcc compiler, I could find that there are still `mov` instructions that handle `stack` pointer and `frame` pointer.

To cut a long story short, I want to know specific case that `mov` instructions are never eliminated by compiler optimization or somethings. I suggest there must be that case.

Comment: If your compiler conforms to the ABI, no. If your compiler doesn't conform to the ABI and can see the entire program, then potentially yes.

Comment: push and pop are psuedo instructions for stm/ldm.

Comment: which arm instruction set are you talking about?

Comment: and how do you plan to survive without mov?  and what compiler as this is highly compiler specific.  just get gcc and look at or modify the sources, this has nothing to do with the instruction set it has to do with the compiler.

Comment: It must be problem specific. Good assembly programmers don't use mov very often, but sometimes it's either impossible or way too inefficient otherwise.

Comment: A cheap trick would be: add/sub y, x, #0; instead of mov y, x; But what's the point?

Comment: Neither push/pop nor procedure calls are related to 'mov' in any way. Aren't you mistaking 'mov' for something else? Pleas be more specific.

Comment: LTO (link time optimization) and `static` will eliminate the need for a compiler to generate ABI prologue and epilogue.  This means that the SSA labeling can be used across functions and no `mov` will be needed.  At some point the ABI (and MOV) maybe desired as the code could be used in some *updated* manner (shared library, etc) where the compiler can not determine register usage by callers.